# Read and write ArrayList<Object> with various type of objects in parcel

Tags: android, file, classloader, parcel

I am using parcel to cache Items in binary file. Everything was fine until I need to store into single `ArrayList` various type of objects:

```
        fout = new FileOutputStream(file);

        Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
        ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(items);
        Log.d(TAG, "write items to cache: " + items.size());
        parcel.writeList(list);
        byte[] data = parcel.marshall();
        fout.write(data);
```

But reading don't work properly:

```
fin = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
fin.read(data);
Log.d(TAG, "file size: " + file.length());

Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
parcel.unmarshall(data, 0, data.length);

ArrayList<Object> rawList = parcel.readArrayList(Object.class.getClassLoader());
```

I think problem is in Object classLoader, who can't create object for extended class.

Have any idea how I can easily fix this? Or maybe could somebody to give me advise for my task which is to cache `ArrayList` or Set into file with objects of type `<? extends Object?>`.
Logcat:

```
08-20 12:16:52.200: D/ItemList(6637): writing data
08-20 12:16:52.200: D/ItemList(6637): write items to cache: 2
08-20 12:17:45.940: D/ItemList(6925): reading data
08-20 12:17:46.650: D/ItemList(6925): reading data
08-20 12:17:47.050: D/ItemList(6925): reading data
08-20 12:17:47.060: D/ItemList(6925): cache file found
08-20 12:31:18.050: D/ItemList(7349): file size: 760
08-20 12:17:47.060: D/ItemList(6925): founded items in cache: 0
```

More logcat:

```
08-20 12:49:02.930: D/ItemList(9241): file size: 1136
08-20 12:49:02.930: D/ItemList(9241): dataAvail(): 0
08-20 12:49:02.930: D/ItemList(9241): dataSize(): 1136
08-20 12:49:02.930: D/ItemList(9241): dataCapacity(): 1136
08-20 12:49:02.930: D/ItemList(9241): founded items in cache: 0
```

Comment: You could try using one of your classes instead of `Object` in `Object.class.getClassLoader()` and see if that helps

Comment: @DavidWasser, I am able to give only one classLoader, but in array is various type of objects. Actualy I give class loader from class, who have right CREATOR static field. But it doesn't work.

Comment: There are no errors in your logcat? No "class not found" errors?

Comment: After `fout.write(data);` do you `call fout.flush()` and/or `fout.close()` before trying to read?

Comment: @DavidWasser: unbelievable but no. There aren't any "class not found" or any entries except my log.

Comment: @DavidWasser: yes, I am closing file corectly and I check file, its not empty. In file editor I see some binary data and some strings with right class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found it. You never **read** the data from the file:

```
fin = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
```

All you do is create the input stream and allocate a byte buffer.

**EDIT Add more code about how to unmarshall the Parcel**

```
Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
parcel.unmarshall(data, 0, data.length);
parcel.setDataPosition(0); // Set the position in the parcel back to the beginning
                           //  so that we can read the stuff out of it
ArrayList<Object> rawList = parcel.readArrayList(Object.class.getClassLoader());
```

Comment: Dear Lord, how big stupid mistake I did. But it doesn't work also. I double checked, file size is 760 bytes.

Comment: Output the result of `fin.read(data);` and make sure that you are actually reading 760 bytes. Also check logcat now for errors.

Comment: no error. Please could you read bottom of my question. I added more logcat with more data from parcel. I think here is parcel issue, because dataAvail() return zero, but I am really sure in data is one ArrayList. But reading array list don't return null.

Comment: dataAvail() returns 0 because there is no more room to write into the Parcel data (ie: the capacity is equal to the amount of data in the Parcel). That's all correct.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MZBXptku this code not work to. I think is issue with marshall or unmarshall

Comment: Yes, for some stupid reason when you call `unmarshall()` the data position is set to the **end** of the byte array instead of to the **beginning**, so it looks like there isn't anything left to read from the parcel. I'll update my answer for you.